# Published posts counter

Tags: posts

I'd like to have statistics for the website. Is there is any snippet to allow WP admin in Dashboard to monitor how many posts published daily or monthly by other users ?

Comment: Sorry, but plugin recommendations are off topic here. Thanks you

Comment: Its already displayed under published posts otherwise you can create a notice in admin using wp_count_posts and admin_notices functions.

Comment: @PieterGoosen i removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use

> wp_count_posts( $type, $perm );

function to count number of posts published

For details please visit [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts)

Comment: but this will be viewed by website visitor. I am looking for something to show counts of published posts in Dashboard only.

Comment: @Kareem You can look at creating your own [Dashboard Widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) then you can get all published posts and count them using the above method.